# "Two step" Markov chain is actually a Markov chian

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, markov-chains, ergodic-theory

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $\mathcal X$ be its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Let $\mathscr P(X)$ be the set of all the Borel probability measures on $X$. A **Markov chain** on $X$ is a measurable map $P:X\to \mathscr P(X)$. We write the image of $x$ under $P$ as $P_x$. (Here $\mathscr P(X)$ is quipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra coming from the weak* topology).

Intuitively, for $E\in \mathcal X$, we think of $P_x(E)$ as the probability of landing inside $E$ in the next step given that we are sitting at $x$ at the current instant.

Now let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $X$. We define a new measure $\nu$ on $X$ as follows:

$$\nu(E) = \int_X P_x(E)\ d\mu(x)$$

Intuitively, suppose in the firt step we land in $X$ according to $\mu$. The probability of landing on $x\in X$ according to the measure $\mu$ is $d\mu(x)$.
Now let the Markov chain $P$ drive us. Then the probability of landing in $E$ in the next step given that we are at $x$ is $P_x(E)$.
So the probability of landing in $E$ in two steps is $\int_X P_x(E)\ d\mu(x)$.

So we have a map $P_\sharp:\mathscr P(X)\to \mathscr P(X)$ which takes a probability measure $\mu$ and produces a new measure $\nu$ as defined above.

Composing $P:X\to \mathscr P(X)$ with $P_\sharp:\mathscr P(X)\to \mathscr P(X)$ we again get a map $X\to \mathscr P(X)$, which I will denote by $P^2$.

> **Question.** Is $P^2$ aslo a Markov chain, that is, is $P^2$ aslo Borel measurable?

My guess is that the map $P_\sharp$ is actually continuous, which would answer the question in the affirmative. But I am not sure.

**EDIT II:**
I tried to argue the measurability of $P_\sharp\circ P$ as follows:

Let $f\in C(X)$ be fixed. 
We need to figure out what is $\int_X f\ d(P_\sharp\mu)$: If $g:X\to \mathbb R$ is the characteristic function of $E\in \mathcal X$, then $\int_X g\ d(P_\sharp\mu)$ is nothing but $\int_XP_x(E)\ d\mu(x)$. So a reasonable guess for $\int_X f\ d(P_\sharp\mu)$ is
$$\int_Xf\ d(P_\sharp\mu) = \int_X \left(\int_X f\ dP_x\right)\ d\mu(x)$$
Write $x\mapsto \int_Xf\ dP_x:X\to \mathbf R$ as $\tilde Pf$ (Note that this is a measuable function and thus the integral above is well-defined).

Now since $C(X)$ is separable, there is a countable dense set $D$ in $C(X)$. This shows that the map $i:\mathscr P(X)\to \prod_{f\in D}\mathbf R$ defined as $\mu\mapsto (\int_X f\ d\mu)_{f\in D}$ is an embedding.
So to check the measurability of $P_\sharp \circ P$ we just need to check the measurability of $\pi_f\circ i\circ P_\sharp\circ P:X\to \mathbf R$ for each $f\in D$.
But this map takes $x$ to
$$\int_X f\ d(P_\sharp P_x) = \int_X \tilde P f\ dP_x = \tilde P(\tilde Pf)(x)$$
Hence this map is measurable and we are done.

**EDIT I: (Please ignore)**

I tried to argue the continuity of $P_\sharp$ as follows:

Let $f\in C(X)$ be fixed. We want to show that the map $\mathscr P(X)\to \mathbb R$ defined as $\mu\mapsto \int_X f\ d(P_\sharp\mu)$ is continuous (This is beacuse $\mathscr P(X)$ has the weak* topology).

So we need to figure out what is $\int_X f\ d(P_\sharp\mu)$. If $g:X\to \mathbb R$ is the characteristic function of $E\in \mathcal X$, then $\int_X g\ d(P_\sharp\mu)$ is nothing but $\int_XP_x(E)\ d\mu(x)$. So a reasonable guess for $\int_X f\ d(P_\sharp\mu)$ is
$$\int_Xf\ d(P_\sharp\mu) = \int_X \left(\int_X f\ dP_x\right)\ d\mu(x)$$
Write $x\mapsto \int_Xf\ dP_x:X\to \mathbf R$ as $\tilde Pf$ (Note that this is a measuable function and thus the integral above is well-defined).

So we want to show that the map $\mathscr P(X)\to \mathbb R$ taking $\mu$ to $\int_X\tilde Pf\ d\mu$ is continuous.

This will be true if $\tilde Pf$ is continuous. $\tilde Pf$ is continuous certainly if $P$ is continuous. But we just have mesurability of $P$ to work with.

Comment: "A Markov chain on X is a measurable map P:X→(X)" Any source for this?

Comment: *Random Walks on Reductive Groups* by Benoist and Quint.

Comment: ...Which could probably rather be titled *On some transformations of transition semi-groups acting on groups*, to avoid the confusion with probabilistic works on random walks in the classical (probabilistic) sense. Anyway, thanks for the reference, and nice question (and I concur with your guess).

Comment: And that gives me the opportunity to ask you: What, according to you, is something that anybody who wants to learn probability theory should read? Right now I am only familiar with probability as used by computer scientists where the framework is mostly just finite probability spaces. (I know basic measure theory and some ergodic theory.)

Comment: There are tons of good choices nowadays, especially if you already have some basics of measure theory in your toolbox. A classical option would be to delve into at least the first chapters of *Probability theory with examples* by Rick Durrett (available on the author's site), but I would add to that the advice to skip as soon as possible to *Probability with martingales* by David Williams (possibly also available on the web), which is smaller but a true delight to read, and then, possibly, to go back and forth between these two.

Comment: I added some details and my faith in the guess is now wavering. So perhaps the map $\mathscr P(X)\to \mathscr P(X)$ is only a measurable map, which would be enough for my purpose, but I do not know of any convenient criterion to check for measurability of a map with $\mathscr P(X)$ as the target.

Comment: I think I have got it. I have added what I am thinking as EDIT II. It seems alright to me but it'll be great if you can have a look. Thanks.